# Using iOS 8 device for testing iOS 7 apps

Tags: ios7, ios8

I wonder if I update my primary testing device to iOS8, will this have a negative effect on testing iOS apps compiled with iOS7 SDK on this device? For example bugs related specifically to iOS8, which would not appear on device running iOS7. What problems should I expect?

Comment: Wouldn't recommend this...

Comment: if you update your devices with iOS8, you will be able to compile with the latest iOS8 SDK only with `Xcode6` (those are betas only), and the beta `Xcode` was usually not capable of submitting applicaitons to AppStore, as far as I know... but I have not tried to do such thing it with Xcode6 at all, but it could be an inconvenient side-effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, you should have one device to test each operating system version you are targeting. Once you upgrade, you will not be able to catch any issues that relate to iOS7.